# Program frozen after memory de-allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-management, dynamic

I have some issues with my code during my memory deallocation process. Here is the error I am getting: [image: I make it to the part where my memory should be deallocated but instead of deallocation I get an infinite loop]

```
bool LinkedList::addArtist(){
    cout << "Enter artist name: ";
    char *name = new char[0]();
    cin >> name;
    cin.ignore(1);
    '/n';

    cout << "Enter artists top story: ";
    char *topStory = new char[0];
    cin >> topStory;
    cin.ignore(1);
    '/n';

    cout << "Enter artist description: ";
    char *description = new char[0];
    cin >> description;
    cin.ignore(1);
    '/n';

    this->addAtBeginning(*&name, *&topStory, *&description);

    cout << "made it out" << endl;
    delete[] name;
    delete[] topStory;
    delete[] description;
    return true;
}
```

As you can see I get the "made it out" notification yet my program gets frozen and doesn't allow me to do anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Allocating no characters at all to store your inputs in is very optimistic; you can't even store empty strings there. This inevitably causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Pease provide textutal information as text, not as picture of text.

Comment: `*&name` is usually written `name`, and similarly for the other two arguments.

Comment: That was  good answer.. I got it to work. Just needed some more characters in allocation.

Comment: A reasonable compiler will say "Warning: statement has no effect" on the lines that say `'/n';`. Are you expecting those to print line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is terrible UB.  You allocate `char` arrays of length `0` and then gently input data into them: Buffer overflow guaranteed !

Try with `string` instead of `char[]`.  Not only can it cope with dynamic length, but in addition it will free you from the duty of manual memory management.

```
bool LinkedList::addArtist(){
    cout << "Enter artist name: ";
    string name;
    getline (cin, name);  // allows blanks in string and ignores \n

    ...      

    this->addAtBeginning(name, topStory, description);

    cout << "made it out" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

If the rest of the code uses `char` arrays in the same manner,  just refactor everything to `string`. But if you would have a lot of code that already works well with char arrays and really don't want to touch it,  then you can pass a `string x;` as a `const char*` parameter with `x.c_str()`.